# Creating HTML table results in extra columns

Tags: php, html, output

I'm trying to pull a sql table and convert to html table.

Main loop:

```
function generate_HTMLTable($data){
$tr="";
    foreach ($data as $row) {      
    $td ="";
    for($i=0; $i<count($row);$i++)     
    $td=$td."<td>$row[$i]</td>\n";  
    $tr=$tr."<tr>".$td."</tr>\n";
}
return "\n<table>".$tr."</table>\n";
 }
```

The actual table has only 4 columns and ten rows, however for some reason, it outputs 8 columns and 10 rows...

`print_r($data)`  yields

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [Place] => 1 
    [0] => 1 
    [Car] => Chev
    [1] => Chev
    [Color] => Black
  ) 
)
```

Comment: `print_r($data)` and show us the results

Comment: You have an array here that holds each column value twice – once under the column name, and once under a numerical index. This is a matter of how you are fetching the database results, so go look in that place.

Comment: This is my select statement

$data = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM questiondata")->fetchAll();

Something to do with the fetchAll() possibly?

Answer (score 1):

The output is correct. Since you are fetching both the column names and indexes via the query, hence you are getting that output.

Instead of `fetchAll()` you can do this:

```
$data = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM questiondata")->fetch_assoc();
```

This will only respond back with the column names and you can then generate correct table format.

You can read more here [PHP Mysqli Result Methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

Edit:

After executing the statement, please use this to get the desired output for PDO:

```
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Edit 2:

Didn't knew you were using Sqlite.

For Sqlite, you can do this:

```
$data = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM questiondata")->fetch(SQLITE_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Returns an error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_assoc()

Comment: @SirN00b Updated!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code and complet yours columns

```
function generate_HTMLTable($data){
$table = "<table>";
$table = $table + "<tr><td>ID</td><td>Nom</td> ... </tr>";
foreach ($data as $row) {      
$table = $table + "<tr><td>"+$row['id']+"</td><td>"+$row['nom']+"</td> ... </tr>";
}
$table = $table + "</table>";
return $table;
```

Comment: you must be complet yours columns names and don't forget to use `fetch_assoc` in query